# library for loading custom maps in android

Tags: android, dictionary, mapping

I am searching for a library that can work similar to google maps (navigation / zooming) where I could load my own maps. Lower capabilities may also be acceptable. My maps are acceptable by [Magellan Explorist GPS](http://www.magellangps.com).

I found
[mAppWidget](http://mapp.android-libraries.com/content/overview): but does not provide GPS support so far.

And I am not really sure if I can load my map (online or offline) in OpenStreetMaps.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: mAppWidget now includes GPS support as of Nov 2011 https://twitter.com/AndroidLibs/status/131325548378079232

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Osmdroid [Osmdroid Home Page](http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/) - specifically the [jar file](http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/downloads/detail?name=osmdroid-android-3.0.5.jar).

You can use [Mobile Atlas Creator](http://mobac.sourceforge.net/) to prepare offline tile sources.

It works well with OpenStreetMap as a tile source. It also caches tiles obtained online, so once you've been to an area and used a particular zoom level, then that tile is saved on your device. The coding is quite similar to GoogleMaps

Comment: I am still quite confused how Osmdroid and OpenStreetMap works. I see that OpenStreetMap has the map from OpenStreetMap Server either created to be online or offline with Mobile Atlas Creator but I have a map from an individual map-provider not Google not OpenStreetMap. So I am searching for library that can take all the map data and provide a mechanism to control the map.