# Indooring maps by Android

Tags: android, imageview, indoor-positioning-system

I'm working on indoor navigation system on Android. so I can't use google maps because I'm not depending on GPS system. 
I'm using native code to build map and drawing paths on the ImageView and adding zooming, scaling and moving on the ImageView .
but this way is too much difficult barbecue I want rotate and move and zoom each object above the image inside ImageView.onDraw() function.
My question there is another way to build indoor map with good view like 3D as a google maps and when rotate or pinch the view all objects rotate and move with the changes?

I will be very grateful for helping.

Comment: This may help you: [mAppWidget](http://mapp.android-libraries.com/content/overview). Also, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7472558/library-for-loading-custom-maps-in-android).

Comment: First of all thank your helping. mAppWidget it is good library but I can't rotate the map ... and suggestion question about library supporting GPS not for building indooring map